# Separar texto por caracter

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
String texto = "Test1-2023-89"
result = texto.split("-")
```

Esto me da como resultado un array ["Test1", "2023", "89"]

Pero me gustaría solo obtener = ["Test1", "2023-89"]

Nota: Pueden existir N caracteres "-", ejemplos:

```
String texto = "Test10-Spain-Random-1" => Resultado esperado: ["Test10", "Spain-Random-1"]

String texto = "55Test-Spain-55-1-tt" => Resultado esperado: ["55Test", "Spain-55-1-tt"]
```

Comment: ¿Qué otros casos de uso tenés? ¿Siempre va a empezar la cadena con caracteres no numéricos?

Comment: @padaleiana editada mi pregunta a tu pregunta

Comment: Hola Sirdaiz, Puedes usar lo siguiente: **String aux = texto.replaceFirst( "-", "/" ); result = aux.split( "/" );**.

Comment: ¿Seguro que es JavaScript?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes separar el texto directamente con una expresión regular dentro del `split()`. La expresión regular hace *match* al primer guion que encuentre en el texto, ignorando las demás, y el `split()` usará a ese primer guion encontrado como separador.

También le pasamos al `2` como argumento para asegurarse de obtener solo 2 elementos en el array devuelto.

##### Ejemplo:

```js
let texto = "Test1-2023-89";
console.log(texto.split(/-(.+)/, 2));
```

##### Más ejemplos:

```js
let texto1 = "Test1-2023-89";
let texto2 = "Test10-Spain-Random-1";
let texto3 = "55Test-Spain-55-1-tt";

console.log(texto1.split(/-(.+)/, 2));
console.log(texto2.split(/-(.+)/, 2));
console.log(texto3.split(/-(.+)/, 2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Podes conseguirlo así:

- Buscamos la primer ocurrencia y la reemplazamos por algún comodín. Por ejemplo `[-]`
- Al resultado obtenido los separamos por el comodín.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
const texto = 'Test1-2023-89';
const resultado = texto.replace('-', '[-]').split('[-]');
console.log(resultado)
```